Help me understand this WP_Query argument
I am trying to understand what arguments are used to order products on a page by using var_dump on $wp_query->query_vars.
I get this arguement that I don't understand how it's working [orderby] => meta.total_sales.double date as I don't see any thing like this in the WP_Query documentation.
Help me understand what meta.total_sales.double is and how it's used.
Thanks!

Third party plugins are off topic for this Stack.
